# HTML/CSS, write completely in Javascript or not

Tags: javascript, html, css

How does generating HTML/CSS directly in HTML/CSS files, compare with generating HTML/CSS in Javascript?

I have written some code in HTML and CSS, but feel I have much more control over what I am doing when writing Javascript, as it is a fully fledged programming language.  Then I have one type of file for the system and can control the structure of the system much better etc.
It has therefore become tempting to simply write everything in Javascript directly.

But what are the downsides of writing HTML/CSS directly in Javascript?

Comment: I must ask: What are the upsides of it????

Comment: I think you are starting a debate on client-side templating. Googling this word and looking for opinions of people about frameworks such as Angular.js should answer your questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1- People who disable javascript can't see your content

2- It takes longer to render everything, since javascript is ran after DOM loads.

3- Search engines can't see what content is on you page

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript is a client-side language — therefore, writing HTML with JS onto a blank page (I guess that is what you are referring to) will be performed on the client side. This makes you lose some degree of control over how HTML and CSS are written to the page, e.g. when the end-user does not have JS-enabled. Most search engine bots also do not have JS enabled, which means your page will be blind to search engines in general.

However, serving HTML and CSS files instead of writing them using JS will allow you to serve files from the server-side. You can insert information into HTML and CSS files from the server side, e.g. using PHP, before they are sent to the user.

In addition, by using JS, you will be losing this control unless you bridge that gap using AJAX.

Answer (score 2):

Before thinking of doing this you need to ask Why are you willing to do it? If it is for practicing and/or developing your JS skills, I understand but it has little practical use.

1. Javascript is a programming language. Although it does have many applications (including in AJAX), it gives you the ability to modify client-side code dynamically. So, the standard practice is to write **static** HTML/CSS files as HTML/CSS respectively and then when you need to trigger something dynamically to modify HTML (or text) or styling (CSS) of the elements, you can use Javascript.
2. As someone else pointed out, search engines / spiders can only access server-sided pages and JS works on client-side so none of your content would be "crawlable" by the search engine spiders.
3. Even though, CSS or rather CSS3 does give you some *limited* ability to perform dynamically alter client-side styling, for example the `:hover` selector or CSS Animations, for more advanced applications, Javascript is used.
4. It is crucial to think by the way, on devices where Javascript is disabled, none of your site pages would load if your site was rendering all the HTML/CSS in Js, purely.

Therefore, it is best to use HTML/CSS for static text/code/styling and JS for dynamically updating your page.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

No current answer adequately address both the advantages and disadvantages to writing HTML or CSS through JavaScript, so I will attempt to address both sides of the issue.

Advantages:

- JavaScript is **reusable**. Elements common to many pages can be shared, and as JavaScript is a language, these common elements can be manipulated to suit the requirements of the page.
- JavaScript can be **consumed** by external sites, allowing a developer to create dynamic content that can be compiled and rendered externally.
- JavaScript can handle robust data through **JSON objects**, which allows for manipulation of data on the client while writing the visual markup.
- JavaScript developers have created many **frameworks**, such as jQuery, that help avoid re-inventing the wheel.

Disadvantages:

- JavaScript must be **executed** by the client, which can take time and impact the performance of your application.
- JavaScript cannot be **crawled** by search engines, which will negatively impact your search engine optimization strategy.
- While rare, JavaScript cannot be used by browsers that do not support it. Users attempting to access your application will see only the HTML markup if they cannot execute JavaScript.
- Incorrect use of JavaScript opens your application to malicious threats, such as [cross-site scripting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting), where static HTML may have never introduced the threat.

As mentioned by Djizeus, frameworks exist that use JavaScript extensively in developing web applications. [AngularJS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AngularJS) is an example of a framework that aims to assist in creating single-page applications through JavaScript (though static HTML and CSS is also utilized).